# neo4django issues: ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined

Tags: python, neo4j, neo4django

I was trying to run the statement:

```
from neo4django.db import models
```

which resulted in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#38>", line 1, in <module>
    from neo4django.db import models
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\neo4django\db\__init__.py", line 68, in <module>
    if getattr(_settings, 'NEO4DJANGO_PROFILE_REQUESTS', False):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 184, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
    raise ImportError("Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable %s is undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

Kindly help me out with this issue.

Comment: Have you made any attempts to debug?

Answer (score 1):

That error is caused because the environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` is not set. This variable is used to tell Django where to look for settings. For example:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings
```

Alternatively you can call `django.conf.settings.configure()` to initialize settings. You can read more about it in the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/settings/#envvar-DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE).

If you are only running tests for neo4django you can use the included neo4django test settings as described [here:](http://neo4django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running-the-test-suite.html?highlight=DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE#running-tests)

```
expor DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=neo4django.tests.test_settings
```